# Oracle - cannot create the desired foreign key constraint

Tags: database, oracle, foreign-key-relationship

Assume the following Oracle tables:

```
table master (
  name    number(18) not null,
  version number(5)  not null,
  constraint master_uq unique(name,version)
)

table child1 (
  master_name not null,
  ....
)

table child2 (
  master_name not null,
  ....
)
.
.
.
table childN (
  master_name not null,
  ....
)
```

The column master_name in the childX tables refers to the master table name column.

The rules are that:

- Every name in the master table is guaranteed to have a row with
  version = 1
- Every name in the master table may also have other versions ie. 2,3 and so on
- The childX tables reference the name but are not interested in the version particularly.

This means that in each tableN the following foreign key can logically be created to the master table...

```
foreign key childX_fk(master_name,1) references master(name,version)
```

Unfortunately, although the Oracle rule that the foreign key in childX references a unique column combination in master is satisfied, Oracle does not like the hard coded 1 value for version in the childX_fk foreign key.

It would be really good for referential integrity to be able to create foreign keys from the various child tables to the master table but I can't see a way of achieving this.

Does anyone have any ideas possibly?

Comment: If the child tables do not care about the version, is there a reason that you are storing history in the `master` table rather than populating a separate history table (i.e. `master_history`)?

Comment: You're missing a `master_master` table where `master_name` is unique

Comment: @Vincent - thanks, yes normally I would go for something like the following:

Comment: @Vincent - thanks, yes normally I would go for something like the following: childN -> master <- masterversion (where the master:masterversion relationship is 1:many. However, in this case master.name is an id and normalising the data causes queries to have to join 3 tables (ie. childN:master:masterversion) instead of 2 as currently (ie. childN:master). This has a negative performance implication that I find difficult to justify and so was hoping that there is some aspect of foreign key syntax that I may be unaware of that would allow me to hard-wire a column value in the referencing table/s)

Comment: @Justin - thanks. I may not have explained very well as this is not really about history data. It is all very much current. For example, at any time a query may say select .... from childN c join master m on (m.name = c.master_name) where m.version = <some version value>

Comment: @all - just to clarify. There is no massive technical benefit to the application of creating a foreign key here that I can see. The benefit I am aiming for is more managerial as it allows us to formally identify which childX table rows/columns relate to which master table rows. This is very valuable as there are many childX tables/columns that relate to master and keeping track is becoming tricky.

Comment: Why don't you use surrogate keys on your master table? Then you could join childN with master on that column.

Comment: @all - unless anyone has any better suggestions then the best approach I can think of is to do as Vincent suggests and split master into master:masterversion tables, creating a foreign key between childX and master and creating a fast-refresh materialized view over master:masterversion and running selects against the materialized view. Please shout with any comments re this approach!

Comment: @mcalmeida - thanks. A surrogate key is new to me conceptually so I've had a quick read and as master.name is a sequence value I understand it to be a surrogate key already. could you possibly explain your thoughts in a bit more detail?

Comment: ok - my apologies all, I'm being a complete idiot. As master.name is really just an ID, I can implement what I refer to above without even using a materialised view. master simply holds name and masterversion holds the master_name and version with a foreign key to master. Likewise childX tables have foreign keys against master (which now has no cognisance of version so the 1 is not required). Select statements now completely ignore master and use master version ie. select .... from childN c join masterversion m on (m.master_name = c.master_name) where m.version = <version> - ta dah!

Comment: I don't understand the reason for having these multiple child tables. Does each not just represent a version number of the master? If so, why is there not one child table with a version number column?

Comment: @David - I'm afraid it's tricky to explain the "why" in detail as the schema is complex but I hope this brief explanation helps clarify: Master is "fairly generically" referenced by many childX tables. The childX tables have vastly different structures and a single childX table can have multiple columns that reference master.

Comment: @Pancho you could add in a redundant "1" to the child table, couldn't you? Even make it a default value.

Comment: @David - thanks. I contemplated this but opted not to go this route as it would have meant adding the redundant "1" to every childX table (of which there are many) and I felt this would dilute the meaning of the table content as the 1 has no relevance to  childX. I have opted for the route in my comment starting "ok - my apologies...". Other than having the overhead of a new master table containing only an ID value, there's no negative performance impact on queries (I ignore this table in queries) and I can create the foreign key relationship from all childX tables. So it's all good.

Comment: @oracle - following from the above discussion, if technically possibly, it would in my opinion be a useful enhancement to allow  static values in foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual Column and use that to reference to the master:

```
create table child1 (
  name    number(18) not null,
  alwaysone number generated always as (case when name1 = name1 then 1 end) virtual,
  foreign key (name,alwaysone) references master(name,version)
);
```

Comment: thanks @Dieter, this is a really interesting approach and would certainly work - without the overhead of physically storing redundant data. I have up-voted it as the approach I would probably take had I not "worked around" the issue, however as it still introduces noise into the table, my first prize remains the ability to implement "foreign key (name,1) references...". Maybe one day Oracle will facilitate this! :o)